# How to manipulate or edit a txt file from textbox and save the modification to the main file or new file

Tags: c#, winforms

I've managed to open a txt file to a ComboBox where it shown only the second element"100", and if I select one of the items in ComboBox will show me the the first element witch is "firstName", the problem is I want to modify the first element from the textbox and save it to the main file or new file on the way that I replace the old element with new one from the textbox and save the file as it was at the beginning

TXT FILE

```
firstName;;;100;;;0;

firstName;;;100;;;1;

firstName;;;100;;;2;

firstName;;;100;;;3;

firstName;;;0100;;;4;

firstName;;;0100;;;5;

firstName;;;0100;;;6;

firstName;;;0100;;;7;

lastName;;;0100;;;0;

lastName;;;0100;;;1;

lastName;;;0100;;;2;

lastName;;;0100;;;3;

lastName;;;0100;;;4;

lastName;;;0100;;;5;

lastName;;;0100;;;6;

lastName;;;0100;;;7;
```

i want to change the first elements from the textbox and replace it with user input and save the file as in it were,
example:

//output

```
john;;;100;;;0;

Patrick;;;100;;;1;

firstName;;;100;;;2;
```

---

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string[] lines;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                openFileDialog.Filter = "txt file (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName);
                    lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName);
                    List<string> result = new List<string>();
                    string[] par = new string[1];
                    par[0] = ";;;";
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string[] row = lines[i].Split(par, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        if (row.Length > 2)
                        {
                            if (!result.Contains(row[1]))
                                result.Add(row[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (string line in result)
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var d = lines;
            var t = d.Where(g => g.Contains(comboBox1.Text));

            string allItems = "";
            foreach (string item in t)
            {
                string[] r = item.Split(new string[] { ";;;" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                allItems += r[0] + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            textBox1.Text = allItems;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to output the contents of textBox1 to a new file? If so, just use [TextBoxBase.Lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0) and pass that to [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=net-7.0#system-io-file-writealllines(system-string-system-string()))?

Comment: Can you give us some more information, please? What does a single line in the text file represent? Do line 1 and 9 correlate (firstName 0 and lastName 0)? Are there always 16 lines or is that dynamic? Is the format a given? What does the combobox contain for entries?

Answer (score 0):

I've read your code carefully and my understanding may not be perfect but it should be close enough that I can help. One way to achieve your objectives is with data binding and I'll demonstrate this step by step.

---

**"open a txt file to a combobox"**

In your main form, you'll move the `OpenFileDialog` so that it is now a member variable:

```
private OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
{
    InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            "Files"),
    FileName = "Data.txt",
    Filter = "txt file (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
    FilterIndex = 2,
    RestoreDirectory = true,
};
```

In the main form CTor

- Handle event `buttonLoad.Click` to display the dialog
- Handle event `openFileDialog.FileOk` to read the file.
- The `DataSource` of `comboBox` will be set to the list of lines read from the file.

**Initialize**

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    buttonLoad.Click += onClickLoad;
    openFileDialog.FileOk += onFileOK;
    comboBox.DataSource = lines;
    .
    .
    .
    Disposed += (sender, e) => openFileDialog.Dispose();
}
BindingList<Line> lines = new BindingList<Line>();
private void onClickLoad(object? sender, EventArgs e) =>
    openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
```

In a minute, we'll look at those three things step by step. But first...

---

**Serialize and Deserialize**

You have a lot of loose code doing string splits to decode your serializer format. Try consolidating this in a class that is also suitable to be used in a `BindingList<Line>`. This will be the data source of your combo box. *Also consider using a standard serialization format like JSON instead!*

```
class Line : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Make a Line from serialized like firstName;;;100;;;0;
    public Line(string serialized)
    {
        // Convert to a stored array
        _deserialized = serialized.Split(new string[] { ";;;" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
    // Convert back to the format used in your file.
    public string Serialized => string.Join(";;;", _deserialized);
    private string[] _deserialized { get; } // Backing store.
    // Convert a list of Lines to a collection of strings (e.g. for Save).
    public static IEnumerable<string> ToAllLines(IEnumerable<Line> lines) =>
        lines.Select(_ => _.Serialized);
    // Determine how a Line will be displayed in the combo box (e.g. "0100").
    public override string ToString() => _deserialized[1].ToString();
    // Use array syntax to access elements of the split array.
    public string this[int index]
    {
        get => _deserialized[index];
        set
        {
            if(!Equals(_deserialized[index],value))
            {
                // Send event when any array value changes.
                _deserialized[index] = value;
                OnPropertyChanged($"{index}");
            }
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

---

**Load**

Once the data file is selected, the raw text file will be shown and the combo box will be populated.

```
private void onFileOK(object? sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    lines.Clear();
    foreach (var serialized in File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog.FileName))
    {
        lines.Add(new Line(serialized));
    }
    textBoxMultiline.Lines = lines.Select(_=>_.Serialized).ToArray();
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

---

**Replacement**

Going back to the main form CTor there are three more events we care about:

```
public MainForm()
{
    .
    .
    .
    comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += onComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged;
    textBoxEditor.TextChanged += onEditorTextChanged;
    lines.ListChanged += onListChanged;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

*When a new item is selected in the combo box, put it in the text editor.*

```
private void onComboBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (Line)comboBox.SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        textBoxEditor.Text = item[0];
    }
}
```

---

*When the textEditor text changes, modify the item.*

```
private void onEditorTextChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (Line)comboBox.SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        item[0] = textBoxEditor.Text;
    }
}
```

---

*When the item changes, update the file display in the big textbox.*

```
private void onListChanged(object? sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ListChangedType)
    {
        case ListChangedType.ItemChanged:
            textBoxMultiline.Lines = lines.Select(_=>_.Serialized).ToArray();
            break;
    }
}
```

[image: replacement]

---

**Save**

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
{
    InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            "Files"),
    FileName = "Data.txt",
    Filter = "txt file (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*",
    FilterIndex = 2,
    RestoreDirectory = true,
};
private void onClickSave(object? sender, EventArgs e) =>
    saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this);
private void onSaveFileOK(object? sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog.FileName, Line.ToAllLines(lines));
}
```

I hope this is "close enough" to what you have described that if will give you some ideas to experiment with.